# How to change date from database to dd/mm/yyyy - php in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

MySQL stores the date in my database (by default) as `YYYY-MM-DD` The field type for my date is `DATE` (I do not need any time storage). Is there a simple way to change it by default to `DD/MM/YYYY`?

Comment: try using date format function in php

Answer (score 2):

The internal storage format of dates in MySQL is usually out of scope for developers and most users of the database.  Basic good practice is to always store date information using a proper date column, such as `datetime`.  With regard to how to *view* your date information in different ways, you may use the `DATE_FORMAT` function.  For example:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2014-02-01', '%d/%m/%Y') AS new_date
FROM dual;

01/02/2014
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `date()` and `strtotime()`

```
date('d/m/Y', strtotime('now'));
```

**OR**

```
date('d-m-Y', strtotime('now'));
```

**OUTPUT**

```
06/06/2018
06-06-2018
```